# MYSQL Search/Wildcards

Tags: mysql

I trying to search a MySQL database using PHP, The search works fine but I'm looking for a little help with wildcards:

The data in the field (Model) I am searching is: "A4" (215 results)

My search string is:

```
SELECT * FROM `temp_comp`.`mvl` WHERE `Model` LIKE '%A4 Avant%'
```

Is there a way I can still search 'A4 Avant' but this will return any fields that contain 'A4' or 'Avant'

The search term is taken from a csv file so I wanted to try and do this without having to split the two words first and search for 'A4' and/or 'Avant', I have tried the following but get no results:

```
SELECT * FROM `temp_comp`.`mvl` WHERE `Model` LIKE '%A4%Avant%'
```

As you may have guessed this is not my normal field so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM temp_comp.mvl WHERE (Model LIKE '%A4%') OR (Model LIKE '%Avant%')
```

If you want to avoid splitting up the test you can use a regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_comp.mvl WHERE Model REGEXP 'A4|Avant'  <<-- Either '%A4% or %Avant%
SELECT * FROM temp_comp.mvl WHERE Model REGEXP 'A4*Avant'  <<-- '%A4%Avant%
```

See the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Hi,Thank you for you reply but I was looking for a way to search this without splitting the two words if this is possible.

Comment: @user1051894, sure, use a regexp

Comment: @user1051894, note that the `|`  searches for A4 **or** Avant. If you want to search for `*A4*Avant*` you need to use `A4*Avant` _(with regexp the beginning and end wildcard is implicit)_

Comment: I have tested this and it works perfect, Thank you for the advice Johan. Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have a built-in way to split strings in a query. Splitting them beforehand and then adding n predicates to the where clause is trivial.

```
SELECT * FROM `temp_comp`.`mvl` 
WHERE `Model` LIKE '%A4%' OR `Model` LIKE '%Avant%';
```

Comment: Hi Jim, This is what I feared but thanks for taking the time to let me know.  
Kind Regards, David

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can achieve this.

Modify your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `temp_comp`.`mvl` WHERE `Model` LIKE '%A4%' AND Model LIKE '%Avant%'
```

The above example will look for elements of the search term in the query in such a manner that they should all be present in the record. And if you want to search for records with either of the search terms, you can replace the word **AND** with **OR** and it does the job.

And ideally, you would follow these steps to prepare for the query:

1. Take the input string to search.
2. Split it by spaces so you have an array of words
3. Loop through the array and build your search string.
4. Use the search string in your query.

Comment: Hi itsols, Thanks for braking this down. I did look at this option but I thought I may have been making more work for myself if there was a mysql option to search. But the replys here have cleared this up. Thanks for your time.